# PyCharm shows wrong project layout after update

Tags: python, layout, pycharm, project

Today after an update to PyCharm 2021.2.2 I found that some projects in my workspace were messed up, for example I see this:

[image]

Instead of this, that I was seeing before PyCharm update:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answering my own question so as to save time for users facing the same issue.)

**EDIT:** found a more stable and faster solution.

In PyCharm > Settings > Project Structure, select the project and remove the useless "Content Roots" at the right on the screen.

[image]

---

---

Old solution for reference:

- Close PyCharm.
- Open the faulty project's `<root>/.idea/<project>.iml` and remove all XML entries that refer to content outside the project:

[image]

- Save the file and reopen PyCharm. The project displays normally again.

Answer (score 2):

For me helped following:

- Close PyCharm
- (Optional) I've also removed the project from my "Recent Projects List"
- Remove `.idea` folder from project root
- Open the project and wait for indexing process