# Pycharm IDE can't run scripts when importing modules

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a script `pycharm_test.py` inside my django app `universe` in my Django project `Finchin` which imports `Cashpool` from my own apps and some further modules from 3rd party `stellar_sdk`:

```
# /Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/apps/universe/pycharm_test.py

import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin")

from apps.cashpool.models import Cashpool  # doesn't work

from stellar_sdk.asset import Asset  # works
from stellar_sdk.keypair import Keypair  # works

def test():
    print('test')

test()
```

Now when i run this script in Pycharm using `rightclick/run 'pycharm_test'` it raises

```
/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/bin/python /Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/apps/universe/pycharm_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/apps/universe/pycharm_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apps.cashpool.models import Cashpool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.cashpool'; 'apps' is not a package
```

**Note:** When I remove `from apps.cashpool.models import Cashpool` the script runs properly. So somehow the `stellar_sdk` imports work.

When I try

```
..
from cashpool.models import Cashpool
..
```

it raises

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

[This](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000058690-Module-not-found-in-PyCharm-but-externally-in-Python) didn't help and I checked the following:

- all dirs have a `__init__.py`
- all apps are included in `settings.py`
- sys path looks satisfying
- the interpreter is linked to the venv

```
# settings.py

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

```
# print(sys.path)

['/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/apps/universe',
 '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9',
 '/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/apps',
 '/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin',
 '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display',
 '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
```

Dirs:

[image]

Venv interpreter:
[image]

Run config:
[image]

OS shell
[image]

Comment: The Python path is not set correctly.  In order for this to work, the directory that contains "apps" must be in `sys.path`.  You can certainly add it there, as long as you know how to get there, like "../..".

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks, how would I add this to sys.path on Mac OS?

Comment: Operating system doesn't matter.  You just do `import sys` / `sys.path.append( ... )`

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks, i included this into my module and receive the same error. Do I have to append the url that contains "apps" relative to the module?

Comment: You don't need the other lines, just the one that ends in "Finchin".  As long as `apps` contains a `__init__.py`, it should work.  Do you have another directory called `apps` in your tree?

Comment: @TimRoberts `__init__.py is available`. There's no other dir called apps. I added a snippage of the tree.

Comment: The error ends by saying `apps is not a package` because it doesn't have an `__init__.py` itself that's why the error is thrown at the line `from apps.cashpool`.

Comment: @bad_coder oh it does, the screenshot truncated it, i updated the tree screenshot - apologize

Comment: In `File` chose `Invalidate caches`. Does that solve it? (Then there are several things here where you duplicate the same step, for example when you add to `sys.path` in your program that's exactly what marking a directory as `sources root` does. Did you somehow install the project to the `site-packages` or are you just adding to `sys.path`? Can you add a screenshot of `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Project Structure`?) Have you [update PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69379983) recently? You should also activate the venv in the last screenshot instead of running from the directory.

Comment: Your screenshot from the settings where the Python interpreter is shown, indicates you've added the Project base directory `PyCharmProjects/Finchin` as "added by user". That should not be added as a "sources root" but as a "content root" [see the difference in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html). Search for this Django specific error `INSTALLED_APPS` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` that's what's missing in your project, otherwise things are on sys.path and it should work. This is Django specific.

Comment: invalidate cache didnt solve it. Will check on SETTINGS_MODULE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying dozens of online solutions I made it happen like so:

- Renaming Finchin/apps to Finchin/applications
- Importing `from Finchin.wsgi import *` into the script

Working solution:

```
# /Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/apps/universe/pycharm_test.py

import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin")

from Finchin.wsgi import *  # import this

from apps.cashpool.models import Cashpool  # works now

from stellar_sdk.asset import Asset  # works
from stellar_sdk.keypair import Keypair  # works

def test():
    print('test')

test()
```

I think as for the first point this caused some conflict with apps dir and apps.py in the apps themselves (however, usually this should work though).

The import of `from Finchin.wsgi import *` probably loads the settings, since without this import it raises

```
/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/bin/python /Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/applications/universe/issue_token.py
['/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/applications/universe', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9', '/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/applications', '/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/applications/universe/issue_token.py", line 17, in <module>
    from applications.cashpool.models import Token
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/applications/cashpool/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class FiatCurrency(models.Model):
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `settings/preferences` dialog box, then open the project interpreters page.
2. Click next to the project interpreters field and choose `Add`. The Add python interpreter dialog box will open.
3. In the left-hand pane of the Add Python interpreter dialog, click the virtual environment node. I am assuming you have your virtual environment set up.
4. Specify the required interpreter using the drop-down list, or click the eclipse button to find one in your file system.
5. Select the check box `Make available to All Projects`

Comment: I have a venv activated which points to the correct python3.9 executable within the interpreter settings